# Slider over ARSCNView in ARKit (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

So I am new to Swift, Xcode and Arkit.
I work with Xcode 9.2

I wanted to build a simple app that places an object when tapped on the screen to the position it detected a plane or point.

I Started up Xcode and wrote this short piece of code into the basic example thats there when u open up with scenekit.
Code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self

        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true

        // Create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
        let result = sceneView.hitTest(touch.location(in: sceneView), types: [ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint])
        guard let hitResult = result.last else {return}
        let hitTransform = SCNMatrix4.init(hitResult.worldTransform)
        let hitVector = SCNVector3Make(hitTransform.m41,hitTransform.m42,hitTransform.m43)
        createBall(position: hitVector)
    }

    func createBall(position: SCNVector3){
        var ballShape = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01)
        var ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: ballShape)

        ballNode.position = position

        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)
    }

    // MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Present an error message to the user
    }

    func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay
    }

    func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required
    }
}
```

I inserted this relevant part:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
        let result = sceneView.hitTest(touch.location(in: sceneView), types: [ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint])
        guard let hitResult = result.last else {return}
        let hitTransform = SCNMatrix4.init(hitResult.worldTransform)
        let hitVector = SCNVector3Make(hitTransform.m41,hitTransform.m42,hitTransform.m43)
        createBall(position: hitVector)
    }

    func createBall(position: SCNVector3){
        var ballShape = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01)
        var ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: ballShape)

        ballNode.position = position

        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)
    }
```

This app runs fine. It places the ball everytime i tap on the screen.
Now I wanted to Add a slider to the Main.Storyboard that changes the size value of the ball to be placed.
Main.Storyboard looks like this:

[image]

When I drag the Slider on the Storyboard Screen, the slider is not added to the scene but it places instead of the ARSCNView to full scale. Then it looks like this:

[image]

What do I have to do to just place the slider over the View? Does this Work with other UI Elements? Is this even possible and how does it work. It's probably simple but it's my first time coding in Xcode.

Comment: If you don’t want a steep learning curve....I recommend learning the basics with small coding snippets in playgrounds. After mastering the basics of each framework, you will understand the xcode interface much easier, particularly the scenekit editor. I’ve added a playground below, which will get you started if you want to take that approach.

Answer (score 6):

You can't Drag&drop UI controls to ARSCNView. (it shouldn't host subviews) You need to

1. drag UIView tou you scene,
2. then drag ARSCNView to it,
3. add constraints (top,bottom,left,right = 0 for example),
4. link your ARSCNView  to sceneView
5. Add your slider. Make sure that slider is above ARSCNView(lower in hierarchy), otherwise it will be hidden behind.

Comment: thanks for the help. so i managed to reconfigure a new view controller.
Can you explain how to link the ARSCNView to the sceneView in the code?
Maybe with a screenshot. I looked up tutorials but didn't find anything

Comment: Drag with pressed ctrl from controoler on side menu to it

Comment: hmm when I try to do this, it ends up with View Controller Scene ->View->ARSCNView in the storyboard layout above the  View Controller Scene ->ViewController and causes a blank black screen. what's missing?

Comment: Check transparency of all elements, make sure that your scene view is below controls you to show (earlier in hierarchy), make sure that scene view initialised and running.

Answer (score 0):

The full coding solution programmatically in a swift playground for scaling a ball.

[image]

```
import ARKit
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport


// Main ARKIT ViewController
class ViewController : UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {

    var ballNode: SCNNode!
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // set the views delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self as! ARSCNViewDelegate
       // show statistics such as fps and timing information
       sceneView.showsStatistics = true
       // Create a new scene 
       sceneView.scene.rootNode
       // Add ligthing
       sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

        // sphere geometry
       let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)

      //Create Node object
      ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
        // position node in scene
     ballNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y:0, z: -1)

     //  add new node to root node
     self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)

     // Add an scaleSlider button
     weak var scaleSlider: UISlider! {
         didSet {
            scaleSlider.transform =  CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2)
        }
     }
     scaleSlider = UISlider()
     scaleSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateScaleWithSlider(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
     scaleSlider.minimumValue = 0
     scaleSlider.maximumValue = 10
        // add scaleSlider to view
    sceneView.addSubview(scaleSlider)

    // Auto Layout
    scaleSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
  }

 override func loadView() {

    sceneView = ARSCNView(frame:CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 500.0, height: 600.0))
    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self 

    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    config.planeDetection = .horizontal

    // Now we'll get messages when planes were detected...
    sceneView.session.delegate = self

    self.view = sceneView
    sceneView.session.run(config)

 }

 func scaleNode(value: Float) {
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1
    ballNode.scale = SCNVector3(value, value, value)
    SCNTransaction.commit()
 }

@IBAction func updateScaleWithSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
    guard let slider = sender as? UISlider else { return }
    scaleNode(value: slider.value)
 }

}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: I got the Slider to work and now the value in a label is changed.
But i dont want to change up the complete code. How can i put the slider value into a variable and use it at: 
var ballShape = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01) (instead of 0.01 the slider value)

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what your asking. But in my solution the ball node gets created and loads in the view at the start. In your case the node is tapped into the view. But in anycase you want to do a scale on the node once its created which is changed up or down by the slider. If the slider is working it should be doing a scale on the ballNode each time the slider is moved.